# Make an images act as text underline

Tags: html, css

I want this pen stroke image to act as a text underline, I almost got it except the fact that the stroke image is equal to the container div width and not the text length width.

```css
h1 { text-align: center; }

.container { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;}

.text-underline {
    background: transparent url("https://cockandbullfestival.co.uk/wp-content/themes/cock_bull/img/nav_underline.png") center bottom repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-underline"> Text With Stroke Underline </h1>
</div>
```

How can I make this stroke image to act as a text underline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider a `span` element *(inline element)* inside the `h1` so you have a shrink-to-fit behavior.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-underline span {
  background: url("https://cockandbullfestival.co.uk/wp-content/themes/cock_bull/img/nav_underline.png") center bottom repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-underline"> <span>Text With Stroke Underline</span> </h1>
</div>
```

It will also work with multiline text

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-underline span {
  background: url("https://cockandbullfestival.co.uk/wp-content/themes/cock_bull/img/nav_underline.png") center bottom repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-underline"> <span>Text With Stroke Underline Underline Underline Underline Underline Underline</span> </h1>
</div>
```